# Prolog permutation extracting solutions

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

```
permutation([], []).
permutation(L, [X|Xs]) :- select(X, L, Rest), permutation(Rest, Xs).
```

If I type `permutation([1,2,3],R)`, the first solution is "[1,2,3]" but how to get to the second one without using ";" or "fail". I need to use the 2nd solution like "[1,3,2]" or so in order compare it to another list.

What I mean is:

```
permutation([], []).
permutation(L, [X|Xs]) :- select(X, L, Rest), permutation(Rest, Xs).

go_perm(L,P) :-     
        L = P,
        write(P),nl.

go_perm(L,P) :- 
        permutation(P,P2), % in this case i wanna get the next solution -.- 
        go_perm(L,P2).
```

If `L = P` then it finishes. Permutation of the first solution for "[1,2,3]" is "[1,2,3]". But that pulls me into stackoverflow because it runs into never-endless thing.
Perhaps you understand me. Thanks!

Comment: What is your code actually trying to do? Currently it seems to make no sense; permutation(L, P) already compares the lists so you don't need to compare again.

Comment: permutation([], []).
permutation(L, [X|Xs]) :- select(X, L, Rest), permutation(Rest, Xs).

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming you want to loop over the solutions to print them

One standard way to accomplish this is to fail and backtrack, as in:

```
print_all_permutations(X)
  :- permutation(X, Y), print(Y), nl, fail ; true.
```

### Assuming you just want to check if a given solution is correct

You are already done. Just call the function with the reference list and the list you want to test:

```
permutation([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]).
```

will return true, because [2, 1, 3] *is* a permutation of [1, 2, 3]. If the second argument is not a permutation, the goal will evaluate to false.

This is the magic of prolog: finding a solution, or checking if a given solution is correct, are the same thing.

### In between: partial solution

The same reasoning still applies:

```
permutation([1, 2, 3], [2, X, 3]).
```

will display the only possible value for X.

Or, if you want the whole list to be the result:

```
X = [2, X, 3], permutation([1, 2, 3], X).
```

Comment: well i tried to use your code, but, i just want to get the solutions of [1,2,3] step by step and then compare it to a fixed list [2,1,3] and finish iff permutation of [1,2,3] reached [2,1,3]...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at various aggregate predicates.  Here, findall would work nicely.  you can invoke it:

```
ListIn=[1,2,3], findall(Perm, permutation(ListIn, Perm), Permutations).
```

This will call permutation on ListIn until it fails.  Each Perm returned by permutation will be collected into the Permutations variable.

Answer (score 0):

`permutation` is a predicate that succeeds when one list is a permutation of the other. You don't actually need to enumerate them; just write `permutation([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])` and Prolog will tell you "true".

Comment: and how to show the solution for permutation([2, _ ,1, _ ],[1,2,3,4]) ? need to print out my sudoku :/

Comment: @viktor: you're not seriously trying to solve sudokus by enumerating permutations, are you?